# Extract values from vector and save in new vector

Tags: matlab, vector, extract

I have a vector *Cycle()* that can contain several elements with a variable size.

I want to extract from this vector all the values which are in the odd columns, i.e. *Cycle(1), Cycle(3), Cycle(5)* ... and save them into a new vector Rcycle.

That's my code:

```
Rcycle = zeros(1, length(cycle)/2);
Rcycle(1) = cycle(1);
for j=3:length(cycle);
    for i=2:length(Rcycle);
        Rcycle(i) = cycle(j);
        j = j+2;
    end
end
```

Also I want to extract from *Cycle()* the even columns and save them in a vector Lcycle. My code:

```
Lcycle = zeros(1, length(cycle)/2);
Lcycle(1) = cycle(2);
for k=4:length(cycle);
    for i=2:length(cycle);
        Lcycle(i) = cycle(k);
        k = k+2;
    end
end
```

By running this for a sample Cycle() with 12 elements I get the right results for Lcycle, but the wrong ones for Rcycle. Also I get the error that my matrix have exceeded its dimension.

Has anyone any idea how to solve this in a more smooth way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vector indexing!

```
Rcyle=cycle(1:2:end); %// Take from cycle starting from 1, each 2, until the end
Lcycle=cycle(2:2:end);%// same, but start at 2.
```